# Looping through a array of objects with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

Given this simple example:

```
const testdata = [
  {
    id: "001",
    name: "Bob",
    comments: [
      {
        id: "01",
        text: "Hello World"
      },
      {
        id: "02",
        text: "Hello Mars"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I would like to output all the comments for this object:

With this I get the id and the name

```
testdata.map(i => { console.log(i.id + i.name)});
```

What is the best way to output the nested array that holds the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an array of `comments` arrays with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const testdata = [{"id":"001","name":"Bob","comments":[{"id":"01","text":"Hello World"},{"id":"02","text":"Hello Mars"}]},{"id":"002","name":"Sara","comments":[{"id":"03","text":"Hello Jupiter"},{"id":"04","text":"Hello Moon"}]}];

const comments = [].concat(...testdata.map((d) => d.comments));

console.log(comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#forEach`.

```js
const testdata = [ { id: "001", name: "Bob", comments: [ { id: "01", text: "Hello World" }, { id: "02", text: "Hello Mars" } ] } ],
      result = testdata.reduce((r, {comments}) => {
        comments.forEach(o => r.push({...o}));
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this one. Nice.

Comment: You can do `testdata.reduce((acc, {comments}) => acc.concat(...comments), [])` also.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
testdata.map(i => i.comments.map(comment => console.log(comment)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display comments then using `forEach` you can achieve this(forEach not create extra variable)

```js
const testdata = [{"id":"001","name":"Bob","comments":[{"id":"01","text":"Hello World"},{"id":"02","text":"Hello Mars"}]},{"id":"002","name":"Sara","comments":[{"id":"03","text":"Hello Jupiter"},{"id":"04","text":"Hello Moon"}]}];

testdata.forEach(x => x.comments.forEach(y => console.log(y)));
```